# How to create unique pairs of numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I'm trying to create some pairs of unique numbers using pretty simple algorithm.
For some unknown reason after compiling Unity goes into an endless "not responding" state. Seems like it's stuck in a do..while loop, but I don't see any reason for that.

```
 //Creating two lists to store random numbers
    List<int> xList = new List<int>();
    List<int> yList = new List<int>();
    int rx, ry;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
            
        // look for numbers until they are unique(while they are in lists)
        do 
        {
            rx = rand.Next(0, width);
            ry = rand.Next(0, height);
        }
        while(xList.Contains(rx) || yList.Contains(ry));
        
        //add them to lists
        xList.Add(rx);
        yList.Add(ry);
        
        Debug.Log(rx + ", " + ry);
        
        // some actions with these numbers
        gridArray[rx,ry].isBomb = true;
        gridArray[rx,ry].changeSprite(bombSprite);
            
    }
```

Comment: if width or height are small (<10), you might have one of the list full of all possibilities. In this case, the loop will continue indefinitely.

Comment: sorry, i deleted my first comment, I was mistaken)

Comment: nevertheless it should be able to generate a unique pair of numbers eventually

Comment: So, not solving you're actual issue completely, I'd suggest alway add a counter to the loop anfd check that you don't loop indefinitely (like no more than 100 times)

Comment: as I understood your loop, if `3` is in the `xList`, then you can never have 3 anymore as rx. So it's not creating "unique pairs", but 2 unique numbers on each list (I don't know hwo to formulate better)

Comment: Pac0, I mean even if the array is 5 by 5, there are 25 unique pairs and I only need 10, I compiled the same code using different compiler(not in unity) and it went well, numbers were generated litterally after a sec

Comment: example: if `width` is 5, then after 5 iterations of the `for` loop, you will have all the 5 possible values in `xList`, and the 6th iterations is going to hang indefintely.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, I understand the mistake now, thx

Comment: ok, I understand your last comment about the 5x5 array, and it makes sense, but that's not what's your code is doing currently.

Comment: with C# you can create pairs of values, I don't remember which C# version unity is using. Sorry, I need to go, don't have time for a proper  answer!

Comment: what is width and height?  They both need to atleast be bigger then 10.

Comment: you array counter should be the number of unique pairs and you width/height have to atleast be bigger then your counter

Comment: Also its worth mentioning you can never have a bomb in the same column or row as another  bomb.

Comment: If that is your intent though I would suggest just generating a list of values from 0 -> N, then create an array where x is the index of the array, and you take a random value from your list, then remove it from the list and assign it to that index...

Comment: _"Seems like it's stuck in a do..while loop, but I don't see any reason for that."_ - then you really need to learn to use a debugger. Set breakpoints in your code, step through it and inspect your variables to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the issue is that once all unique numbers have been used once you are stuck in the `do - while` loop.

Instead you should rather simply

1. generate the plain index lists for all possible pairs.

   I will use the Unit built-in type [`Vector2Int`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.html) but you could do the same using your own struct/class
2. For each bomb to place pick a random entry from the list of pairs
3. Remove according random picked item from the pairs so it is not available anymore in the next go

Something like

```
// create the plain pair list
var pairs = new List<Vector2Int>(width * height);
for(var x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for(var y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        pairs.Add(new Vector2Int(x,y));
    }
}
// so now you have all possible permutations in one list

if(pairs.Count < BOMB_AMOUNT_TO_PLACE)
{
    Debug.LogError("You are trying more bombs than there are fields in the grid!");
    return;
}

// Now place your bombs one by one on a random spot in the grid
for(var i = 0; i < BOMB_AMOUNT_TO_PLACE; i++)
{
    // now all you need to do is pick one random index from the possible entries
    var randomIndexInPairs = Random.Range(0, pairs.Count);
    var randomPair = pairs[randomIndexInPairs];

    // and at the same time remove the according entry
    pairs.RemoveAt(randomIndexInPairs);

    // Now you have completely unique but random index pairs
    var rx = randomPair.x;
    var ry = randomPair.y;

    gridArray[rx, ry].isBomb = true;
    gridArray[rx, ry].changeSprite(bombSprite);
}
```

---

Depending on your use-case as alternative to generate the pairs list and then remove entries again you could also generate it once and then use

```
if(pairs.Count < BOMB_AMOUNT_TO_PLACE)
{
    Debug.LogError("You are trying more bombs than there are fields in the grid!");
    return;
}

var random = new System.Random();
var shuffledPairs = pairs.OrderBy(e => random.Next());

for(var i = 0; i < BOMB_AMOUNT_TO_PLACE; i++)
{
    // then you can directly use
    var randomPair = shuffledPairs[i];

    // Now you have completely unique but random index pairs
    var rx = randomPair.x;
    var ry = randomPair.y;

    gridArray[rx, ry].isBomb = true;
    gridArray[rx, ry].changeSprite(bombSprite);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your algorithm is maybe not the best way to generate ten bombs in a grid, it should work.
The problem is that your while condition is using a OR statement, which means that if you have a bomb in the first line (in any column), it will not be able to add another bomb in that line.

Therefore you will pretty soon end up with an infinite loop because for every bomb you lock the line and column.

If you put an AND condition, you make sure the pair is unique because you lock only that cell.

Provided of course that width x height is more than ten.